# VideoJS responsive two videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I have two videos on one page, implemented with VideoJS. I want to make them responsive and found the following article regarding this topic: [Making Video.js Fluid for RWD](http://daverupert.com/2012/05/making-video-js-fluid-for-rwd/)

But unfortunately I can't get it to work with both videos, whatever I tried it always works with just one of them.. Do you have any idea how I have to alter the javascript code to make it work with both? I even tried to make two functions and renaming all variables.

Here is my sample html:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"  poster="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video1/spot_01_still.jpg" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
        <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video1/spot_01.flv" type='video/flv'>
        <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video1/spot_01.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    <video id="my_video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" poster="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video2/spot_02_still.jpg" data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
        <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video2/spot_02.flv" type='video/flv'>
        <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/videos/video2/spot_02.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.videoWrapper video {
max-width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}

#my_video_1, 
#my_video_2 {
    width:100% ;
    height:auto ;
}
```

and the js:

```
 _V_("my_video_1").ready(function(){
var myPlayer = this;    // Store the video object
var aspectRatio = 9/16; // Make up an aspect ratio

function resizeVideoJS(){
  // Get the parent element's actual width
  var width = document.getElementById(myPlayer.id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
  // Set width to fill parent element, Set height
  myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );
}

resizeVideoJS(); // Initialize the function
window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; // Call the function on resize
});
```

Comment: You may be leaving it out for brevity, but are you calling `.ready` on both my_video_1 and my_video_2? If not then I would guess that that's your problem.

Comment: yes, I did call it on both..

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on a script which deals with multiple video players using video js - which are also responsive. You can find my article (which also shows an example) here = http://www.andy-howard.com/videojsmultipleresponsivevideos/index.html

This also includes a provided callback function if you require it.

Comment: Here is a good example of why answers should always include the code and not just a link to the code. 404 error!

Comment: Sorry I had to combine 2 tutorials into 1 to make it work. Here's the new url = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html in this instance I had to provide just the link as a lot of things were changed from the original video js folder that I was provided with. Code examples are fine if there's 1 or 2 of them, but a whole folder full of changes is too much to describe all here.